# typescript cannot recognize .sequelizerc file

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli, sequelize-typescript

I have this .sequelizerc file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  config: path.resolve('.', 'src/config/sequelizeCLIConfig.json'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('.', 'db', 'migrations'),
};
```

And then I have a .ts file that generates the cli config file named `generateSequelizeCLIConfig.ts`, which does the following thing:

```
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import config from '../../src/config';
import sequelizeRC from '../../.sequelizerc';

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

const targetFile = path.resolve(sequelizeRC.config);

const sequelizeCLIConfig: Record<string, any> = {};
sequelizeCLIConfig[env] = config.db;

fs.writeFile(targetFile, JSON.stringify(sequelizeCLIConfig, null, 4), err => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  console.log('The sequelizeCLI config file was saved at ' + targetFile + '!');
});
```

The plan is, every time I need migration, I run this script first. This script grabs the data from the config folder and generate the `src/config/sequelizeCLIConfig.json`. And then I run the migration with config data from this .json file.

So the file structure is this:

```
-.sequelizerc
-db
  |-scripts
    |-generateSequelizeCLIConfig.ts
-src
  |-config
    |-index.ts
.sequelizerc
```

However I got this error when compiling `generateSequelizeCLIConfig.ts`:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
db/scripts/generateSequelizeCLIConfig.ts(4,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../.sequelizerc'.
```

So it seems .sequrlizerc is not recognized although I have double checked that this file does exist.

My guess is, .sequelizerc behind the scene is a .js file, not a .ts file, and this gives me some trouble. But I don't know how to verify this, nor how to fix it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add the `.sequelizerc` to your include in  your `tsconfig` as follows:

```json
{
 ..prev configs...,
include: [ ...your paths..., ".sequelizerc"],

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Delete dot. Rename the .sequelizerc to sequelizerc